# How to modify a jquery html clone and insert multiple times after a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html structure like this.

```
<div id='mydiv'> 
   <span class="tobecloned">  some heavy dom <br/> </span>
   <span class="tobecloned">  some heavy dom  <br/></span>
   <span class="tobecloned" id="last">  last some heavy dom  <br/></span>
</div>
```

Now I want to clone the last `span.tobecloned` modify this clone and insert all modified clone instances multiple times after the last `span.tobecloned`.

Modification and insertion will happen in a for loop, I am trying something like this:

```
lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();
cloneHtml = $('.tobecloned').last().clone();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Here I am making enough changes in cloneHtml
   console.log(i);
   cloneHtml.attr('status', i + 1);
   cloneHtml.insertAfter($('.tobecloned').last());
 }
```

Above loop runs 4 times but adds cloned element only once. Here is the demo to reproduce the issue http://jsfiddle.net/illumine/SN4rr/

How can I fix this?

Also notice that I am adding new attributes in the `for` loop. In practical application I'll be modifying more attribute not just 1 or 2.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're trying to make?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var cloneHtml = $('.tobecloned').last().clone();
    var lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();
    // Here I am making enough changes in cloneHtml
    console.log(i);
    cloneHtml.attr('status', i + 1);
    cloneHtml.insertAfter($('.tobecloned').last());
}
```

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vL9YU/

Answer (score 5):

```
var $lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var $clone = $lastSpan.clone();
    $clone.attr('status', i + 1)
          .appendTo($lastSpan.parent());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `for` loop, `cloneHtml` is a jQuery object. If you try to `insertAfter()` it several times, it will simply move. Use `.clone()` inside the loop, before every edit.:

```
lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Here I am making enough changes in cloneHtml
    console.log(i);
    cloneHtml = lastSpan.clone();
    cloneHtml.attr('status', i + 1);
    cloneHtml.insertAfter($('.tobecloned').last());
}
```

Edit: sorry, cloning twice here... Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you clone the element you are creating a new element, so when you add that you can only add it once.  Adding it again simply adds the same element, but doesn't duplicate it.

Create a new clone each time you want to add one...

```
lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   cloneHtml = $('.tobecloned').last().clone();
    // Here I am making enough changes in cloneHtml
   console.log(i);
   cloneHtml.attr('status', i + 1);
   cloneHtml.insertAfter($('.tobecloned').last());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/SN4rr/4/

**JS:-**

```
lastSpan = $('.tobecloned').last();

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Here I am making enough changes in cloneHtml
    console.log(i);
    cloneHtml = $('.tobecloned').last().clone();
    cloneHtml.attr('status', i + 1);
    cloneHtml.insertAfter($('.tobecloned').last());
}
```